# Hiding and showing markers won't appear after being dragged in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The title kinda says it all, i have a google maps api v3 and everything works fine except for one annoying new feature which i cant seem to fix.

You can show and hide markers by a click of a button which calls togglePOI(), but when i drag a marker and click hide and show again. All the markers appear except for the ones i have been dragging around. So the dragging seems to throw things into chaos. I’ve been have headaches over this one so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I cannot paste all the code in here, but if you want to see some other aspect that you think is causing this just ask and ill put it in.

```
var latlngs = new google.maps.MVCArray();   

Map init etc
Marker creation

google.maps.event.addListener(locationMarker, "drag", function()
{
  var index = findMarkerIndex(locationMarker, 1);

  if (index >= 0)
  {
    var nLatLng = locationMarker.getPosition();
    latlngs.setAt(index, nLatLng);

    var nLat = nLatLng.lat();
    var nLng = nLatLng.lng();

    var modifiedLocation = {
      Latitude: nLat,
      Longitude: nLng
    };

    //SEND OUTPUT TO SELECT BOX
    locations[index] = modifiedLocation;
    document.getElementById('locations').options[index] = new Option('Num: ' + index + ' Pois: ' + nLat + ' - ' + nLng, data[4] + ',' + nLat + ',' + nLng + ',' + data[5]);
  }
});


//FUNCTION CALLED FROM HTML BUTTON
function togglePOI()
{
    if(togglePOIBool)
    {
      for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++) 
      {
        if (markers[i].category == 1) //ONLY HIDE CAT 1
          markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      togglePOIBool = false;
      $("#togglePOIButton").val('Aan');
    }
    else
    {
      for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++) 
      {
        if (markers[i].category == 1)//ONLY SHOW CAT 1
          markers[i].setMap(map);
      }
      togglePOIBool = true;
      $("#togglePOIButton").val('Uit');
    }
}

// Returns the index of the marker in the polyline.
function findMarkerIndex(locationMarker, option)
{
  var index = -1;

  for (var  i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) 
  {
    if (markers[i] == locationMarker) 
    {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's OK for your application, replace setMap's with setVisible(true/false). When I tried this, it solves your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/F3XbV/

Comment: ow nice worked like a charm, and its way faster since it doesn't have to load in all the markers again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving that position into `markers` array, I think it could solve the problem, insert this inside `drag` event:

```
markers[index].setPosition(locationMarker.getPosition());
```